# Options on all Angular Chosen (plugin) select elements disappear when any are selected

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

Admittedly, I know just enough about Angular to be dangerous. However, I'm fairly certain I've followed the instructions for the plugin concisely.

The issue is: whenever I select any of the options from one of my select fields using the chosen plugin (City, Nationality, Hotel, Room Type...) the result never gets populated, and the results from all the other select fields disappear. I'm fairly certain this is user error on my part - any clarification or help is much appreciated.

You can see an example here: http://casamarelanoivas.com.br/sst/test/

Thanks.
Kyle

Comment: You need to add some code, please add at least the scope param with contents of the drop downs (2 or more) with relevant html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the selected value in your list to the same model variable you are using to generate the dropdown list.  So whenever you select a value from the drop down list, you are wiping out the list values.

Here is what you have:

```
<select ng-model="model.cities" ng-options="city.name for city in model.cities">
```

This is the pattern you want to use instead.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.name for city in model.cities">
```

In your controller you can then get the selected value from `$scope.selectedCity`

Comment: You saved the day Jon! Thanks a bunch for taking the time to share some knowledge. All the best.